# Running external commands in IPython

Tags: subprocess, ipython, execution

I'd like to run a new command from IPython configuration and capture its output. Basically, I'd like to access the equivalent of `!command` via normal functions. I know I can just use `subprocess`, but since IPython already provides this functionality, I guess there must be a properly made wrapper included somewhere in the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, such wrapper can be called via `ip.IP.getoutput("command")`.